# Время JavaScript в реальном времени на странице

Tags: javascript, время

Есть такой простой код по выведению времени на страницу:

```
var Date = new Date();
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML= (Date.getHours()+":"+Date.getMinutes()+":"+Date.getSeconds());
```

Проблема в том, что он выводит время когда загрузилась страница и все.
Как сделать так, чтобы время на странице обновлялось постоянно, то есть в реальном времени?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, время будет обновляться **каждую** секунду.

Подробней о [`setInterval()`](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval).

```js
var time = setInterval(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = (date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds());
}, 1000);

// Остановить исполнение можно вызовом clearInterval(time).
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: в общем я только учусь js... у меня в браузерах эти коды не работают :-( ни один

Comment: Добавьте еще в код ведущие нули например через `return (n < 10) ? ('0' + n) : ('' + n);`